# How to use props in <script setup> in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Just like the title says,
related Links:
[New `script setup` (without ref sugar)](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/227)

```
<template>
  <TopNavbar title="room" />
  <div>
    {{ no }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import TopNavbar from '@/layout/TopNavbar.vue'
import { defineProps, reactive } from 'vue'

defineProps({
  no: String
})

const state = reactive({
  room: {}
})

const init = async () => {
  // I want use props in this
  // const { data } = await getRoomByNo(props.no)
  // console.log(data);
}
init()

</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

To use props with `<script setup>` you need to call `defineProps()` with the component prop options as the argument, this defines the props on the component instance and returns a `reactive` object with the props which you can use as follows:

```html
<template>
  <TopNavbar title="room" />
  <div>
    {{ no }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import TopNavbar from "@/layout/TopNavbar.vue";
import { defineProps, reactive } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  no: String,
});

const { no } = toRefs(props);

const state = reactive({
  room: {},
});

const init = async () => {
  const { data } = await getRoomByNo(no.value);
  console.log(data);
};

init();
</script>
```

If you are using typescript the alternative way to do this is pass a type only declaration and infer the prop types from that. Pro's are that you'll get stricter type safety <strike>but you cannot have default values.</strike>

```html
<template>
  <TopNavbar title="room" />
  <div>
    {{ no }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import TopNavbar from "@/layout/TopNavbar.vue";
import { defineProps, reactive } from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{
  no: string,
}>();

const { no } = toRefs(props);

const state = reactive({
  room: {},
});

const init = async () => {
  const { data } = await getRoomByNo(no.value);
  console.log(data);
};

init();
</script>
```

### EDIT

Defaults with type only props are now possible:

```
interface Props {
  msg?: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  msg: 'hello'
})
```

Comment: FYI: I also needed to import 'toRefs' from vue

Comment: Note that `toRefs` is only needed if you want to destructure (or "split") props to pass a single prop to a composition function as ref for example. In other cases, just use `props.propName` directly

Answer (score 24):

Very simple answer using features from Vue-3.1 and later:

#### `CircleImage.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="px-4 w-8/12 sm:w-3/12">
    <img :src="src" :alt="alt" class="border-none rounded-full h-auto max-w-full align-middle" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  src: String,
  alt: String,
})
</script>
```

#### `MyView.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
    <CircleImage src="/file1.jpg" alt="one" />
    <CircleImage src="/file2.svg" alt="two" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import CircleImage from '@/components/CircleImage.vue'
</script>
```

See also the documentation: [Declaring props or additional options](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/sfc-improvements/active-rfcs/0000-sfc-script-setup.md#using-setup-arguments)

Comment: I've edited your answer based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74534343/8816585 `.view` is probably a typo and should be `.vue` rather. Please correct me if it's wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I read "New`script setup`" and found the answer

first,use variable save `defineProps`

```
const props = defineProps({
  no: String
})
```

then use it

```
const init = async () => {
  console.log(props.no);
}
```

this is all code:

```
<template>
  <TopNavbar title="room" />
  <div>
    {{ no }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import TopNavbar from '@/layout/TopNavbar.vue'
import { defineProps, reactive, useContext } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  no: String
})

const state = reactive({
  room: {}
})

const init = async () => {
  console.log(props.no);
}
init()

</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

No need to call explicitly `withDefaults`

```html
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

defineProps({
  isOpen: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Got any official reference for that one?

Comment: I was trying with withDefaults and my Props were not working. Thanks for your solution. 

Answer (score 4):

Edit: This answer is outdated. The RFC was changed to use `defineProps(..)`, which is auto-imported if using SFCs.

As per the [ongoing RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/sfc-improvements/active-rfcs/0000-sfc-script-setup.md#using-setup-arguments), the `setup` tag can have a string following where you can define which context you wish to have, like so:

```html
<script setup="props, { emit }">
import { watchEffect } from 'vue';

watchEffect(() => console.log(props.msg));
emit('foo');
</script>
```

These are the same arguments that the `setup()` method receives.

Comment: That RFC is from a stale branch and was superseded:

PR - https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/227
Rendered - https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0040-script-setup.md

Answer (score 2):

if you need your props to be reactive you can get them in your child component like this:

```
const props = defineProps({
    no: String,
    myIdOfSomething: Number
})

const { no, myIdOfSomething } = toRefs(props);

console.log(no.value)
console.log(myIdOfSomething.value)
```

source https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits

Answer (score 1):

Using **Typescript** you could define your props in two syntaxes :

1. **First syntax**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import {PropType} from 'vue'

const props=defineProps({
   color:{
      type:String as PropType<'primary'|'info'|'success'|'error'|'warning'>,
      default :'primary'
    }
})

</script>
```

2. **Second syntax**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

type Color='primary'|'info'|'success'|'error'|'warning'

const props=defineProps<{color:Color}>()

</script>
```

This syntax supports only :

- A type literal
- A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Typescript` and also want to add a default value, you can use this syntax.

```
<script setup lang="ts">

interface Props {
 disabled?: boolean;
 loading?: boolean;
 bordered?: boolean;
 label: string;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
 label: "Button Label",
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if your are not using Typescript?