# Vue.js - ReferenceError: defineProps is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue 3 app. This app relies on Vite, Vue Router, Pinia. The specific versions are:

- Vue: 3.2.31
- Vue Router: 4.0.13
- Pinia: 2.0.11

This app has a single file component that represents a "page". This single file component is defined like this:

**page.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    Hello! Thank you for visiting {{ id }}!
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { onMounted } from 'vue';
    import { useStore } from '../stores/store';

    const myStore = useStore();

    onMounted(() => {
        const props = defineProps({ id:Number });    
        console.log(props);
    });
</script>
```

My goal is such that when someone visits `https://[my-site].com/pages/{some-id}`, I get the `id` passed in via the URL. Currently, my route is defined like this:

```
{
  path: '/pages/:id',
  name: 'page',
  component: () => import('../views/page.vue'),
  props: true
}
```

From my understanding, since `id` is a parameter on my route, I can use the `[defineProps][1]` method. While the single file component loads, I do not see the `id`. In addition, when I look in the console log, I see the following:

*Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: defineProps is not defined*

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Other questions I've seen mention changing ESLINT. However, I'm not using ESLINT in my app. I am using Vite. How do I fix this error?

Comment: defineProps is compile-time syntactic sugar, https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

Answer (score 25):

I had the same error with a much simpler code. I got rid of the error by adding an entry in my ***package.json*** (using Webstorm created project...)

```
"eslintConfig": {
"root": true,
"env": {
  "node": true,
  "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true
},
"extends": [
  "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
  "eslint:recommended"
]
}
```

This website helped me fix my issue: [ESLint | Fix defineProps](https://dev.to/imomaliev/til-2021-10-04-fix-script-setup-defineprops-is-not-defined-38ic)

Answer (score 23):

`defineProps` is a compiler macro for use in `<script setup>`. The macro gets compiled away, and cannot be inside a lifecycle hook, as you observed with `onMounted()`. In addition, it doesn't make sense to define props inside `onMounted()` because the props need to exist before the component mounts.

Props must be declared at the top level of the `<script setup>` context:

```html
<script setup>
    import { onMounted } from 'vue';
    import { useStore } from '../stores/store';

    const myStore = useStore();

    const props = defineProps({ id:Number }); // ✅

    onMounted(() => {
        // const props = defineProps({ id:Number }); // ❌ move to top level
        console.log(props);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 14):

If you're using `<script setup>` *with* `toRefs(defineProps())` then this error shows up.

The solution is found in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66680351/622287).

**TL;DR:**

```js
import { toRefs, defineProps } from 'vue';

// This throws an error:
// const { myProp } = toRefs(defineProps({ myProp: Object }));

// Break it into two lines and the error goes away:
const props = defineProps({ myProp: Object });
const { myProp } = toRefs(props);
```

Answer (score 4):

By adding this to your eslintrc

```
"env": {
  "node": true,
  "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true
},
```

it should remove the eslint error