# What does a ".view" extension mean in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I was reading answers to a Stack Overflow question when I came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68406514/4115031), which has the file names in its example code ending in `.view`.

My experience with Vue has been that the [single-file components](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html) always have their filenames end in `.vue`.

I looked online and couldn't find any other references to the `.view` extension.

Is there such a thing as a `.view` file in Vue?  Or was this more likely a typo?

Comment: I think it's an error and it should have been `.vue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the fact that [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938111/oho) who posted the answer has apparently no knowledge in Vue (or frontend), I assume this is quite a typo indeed.
There is no such thing in Vue. Especially since the answer is using `script setup`, which is quite specific to Vue, since it's some sugar syntax.

I've edited his answer to fix the typo.
[I have notified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382293/how-to-use-props-in-script-setup-in-vue3/68406514#comment131571460_68406514) the answerer of it, he may come back here at some point if he founds out that my edit was wrong.

Vue comes from `View`, and `Vue` is the french word for it. The confusion is understandable but there is no such things as `.view`.
There are no other tags like Laravel, Ruby on Rails or alike, so 100% a typo.